# Virtual Com over TCP/IP

Tags: tcp-ip, порты

- Скажите, есть ли какие нибудь софты, которые умеють создавать виртуальный сом порт(мульти) к удаленному устройству (конвертеру, по ip ).
- Данное время у меня есть софт от так называемой [HW Group](http://www.hw-group.com) . Все бы отлично только у нее есть ограничение только на одного порта, `есть мульти портовая версия`, но она только для специфических устройств `(HW GRoup - ских)` - для меня не подходить.

***Буду рад любым подсказкам / ответам!***

Answer (score 1):

что-то типо этого:

```
netcat -l 3333 > /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: Добавлю, есть еще фичастая штука [x]inetd .

Comment: предполагаю что это линуксовская команда..Верно?

Comment: Верно, а если есть задача, не привязанная к операционке, зачем использовать закрытые и платные решения, хотя есть свободные и бесплатные?

Comment: @ArcherGodson, можно подробнее плиз..

Comment: в линуксе порты имеют примерно такой путь /dev/tty[USB|S][0-9], например, /dev/ttyS0, порт, как и любое устройство ввода-вывода имеет возможность ввода, через    cat data.file > /dev/ttyS0и вывод    cat /dev/ttyS0 > dete.fileно это всё не всегда корректно, так что лучше почитать гугл по ключевым словам "linux shell serial port", там всё не сложно.а netcat - это тулза для.. блин.. да и про [неё есть в гугле][1]  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть ещё: http://www.advancedvirtualcomport.com/ Дорого, но если подумать, то и не очень.